# Fedora installation / mount point

Tags: fedora, mount, system-installation

I am at a loss of what to put in `mount point` during the installation process.

Have Windows partitions and left 500gb of space for fedora (only one partition made on windows), reading fedora's documentation there are supposed to be three partitions? root, boot, swap and maybe more?

I don't understand any of that. What is it that I am supposed to put in `mount point` to have the whole system in one partition? or for the installation process to split the partition I gave of 500 gb into the necessary parts by itself?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have as many or as few partitions as you like.  Many suggest keeping `/boot` separate, mainly because some BIOS have trouble booting if the boot files are too far away from the start of the disk.  You can have a `swap` partition, but a file works just as well.

In the recommended case, you will create three partitions:

- One likely formatted Ext2 or FAT*, with mount point `/boot`
- One likely formatted Ext4 or similar, with mount point `/`, and
- A swap partition, which doesn't have a mount point

If you want to stray from this recommendation and use only a single partition, you want the one with mount point `/`, the root of the filesystem.  If you take this approach, then it is recommended that you create a swap file somewhere on this partition so that the system doesn't crash if you use all of your memory.

Any directory can be its own partition though.  Some that are commonly split out are:

- `/boot` for your kernel and `initrd` — boot files
- `/home` for all of your own files
- `/var` for read-write files (in case you want to make `/` read-only)
- `/` for the system itself — programs, libraries, configuration, etc.
- `/usr` is sometimes separate from `/` but contains the same kinds of things

If you are using (U)EFI to boot instead of the old BIOS, you will likely not want a separate `/boot` partition, but you will want to mount the system EFI partition as `/boot/efi`.  However, you should not reformat this partition, as it contains the boot files for any other operating systems installed as well.

Usually the installer will give you either a graphical utility to manage partitions, or a shell from which you can use `fdisk`.  You do want to be careful not to change your Windows partitions, though — and have a backup just in case, since you are modifying the drive layout.

On the system from which I am typing, I have

- `/boot` of 200M
- `swap` of 16G
- `/` of 40G
- `/var` of 40G
- `/home` of 835G

The `/var` partition is much larger than necessary, and in fact would fit well within the free space of `/`.

Comment: But i dont get it, how do i create them if the disk partition is only one? and which one will be the one that will have all my files? (almost 500 gb)

Comment: so I should create, boot, root and home? That's what I have gotten from reading online, not sure how though.

Comment: So I think i am understanding a little more, sorry if i am too lost. Had the big partition done already so shrunk it to 450 gb and left it as /home, made /root with 30 gb, /boot with 1gb, and swap with 5 gb. Is that fine? are the proportions alright?

Comment: Yes that's what i meant with root. Ok, so i tried putting done and it said I was missing a `/boot/efi` partition. I created it. What's the difference with `/boot`?

Comment: and it's also not letting me make the /boot partition greater than 1 MB, even if i put more.

Comment: I only had the 500 gb partition made along side the windows one, i dont think I had any other free space, i created the boot one first but it set the top as 1024 kb. I think i will go back to windows and see the partitions i have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58330/discussion-between-fox-and-m-o).

Answer (score 1):

You *can* configure an existing partition; in this case, make the mount point `/` — or "root" (but note this is separate from both the administrative account `root` *and* the `/root` directory, which is the home directory for that account). This will leave you without swap (by default), which is probably okay, and with `/home` on the same partition, which is also okay but less convenient should you ever decide to reinstall.

What I'd suggest doing is using automatic partitioning in combination with `I would like to make additional space available`. After you select that and press "Done", you will get a dialog from which you can select the partition you created to put Fedora on. That partition will be removed and replaced with the automatic partitioning scheme (which will include separate `/`, `/home`, and `swap`).

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked for me